# Is it possible to style input type=range with just a left and right color and no thumb?

Tags: html, css

An `<input type="range">` looks like this on Chrome(103)/MacOS

[image]

And this in Firefox(101)

[image]

Is there a CSS only way to get it to look like this?

[image]

It seems so close, just

1. Hide the thumb (easy)
2. Set the border-radius to none (easy)
3. Set the border to none (easy)
4. Set a size (easy)
5. Set the color left of the track different than the right (???)

But I've had no luck

```css
input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: none;
  background-color: blue;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
```

In particular step 5. Is there a way to set left and right colors of the track? Ideally cross browser?

I was trying to think if there was away to use `calc` and a `::before` pseudo element or some recently introduced CSS features like css container queries but nothing came to mind.

PS: I know it's relatively easy to do this in JavaScript by coding my own slider using divs or other elements but I'd love to do it CSS only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example.

```js
function sliderValueChange(e) {
  console.log(e.value);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --slider-width: 300px;
  --slider-height: 20px;
}

input[type='range'] {
  cursor: ew-resize;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  input[type='range'] {
    width: var(--slider-width);
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #353535;
  }
  input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: var(--slider-height);
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    color: #13bba4;
    margin-top: -1px;
  }
  input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    width: 0px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: var(--slider-height);
    box-shadow: calc(-1 * var(--slider-width)) 0 0 var(--slider-width) #43e5f7;
  }
}

/* FF */
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
  background-color: #43e5f7; 
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  height: var(--slider-height);
  width: 0;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: calc(-1 * var(--slider-width)) 0 0 var(--slider-width) #43e5f7;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* IE */
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background-color: #43e5f7; 
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {  
  background-color: #13bba4;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" onchange="sliderValueChange(this)">
```

Comment: Why, it seems to be working perfectly for me. Can you please point out the issues? What browser are you using?

Comment: its an range sldier with a thumb and just a black background. The intended design is to **not** have a thumb and to show the range left of the thumb to be colored in blue. See the last gif that the OP provided.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not get you. It works just fine for me on Chrome, and looks alike the last GIF in the OP's question.

Comment: And there we have the major issue. It only works on chrome but no other browser

Comment: @AlvéMonke, thank you for the example. Yea it only works in chrome but at least it's step in the right direction

Comment: Good work, now it is practical. However you still should add an sufficient explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! If it weren't for you, I would not have worked upon making it run in Firefox. Thanks, once again.

Comment: @AlvéMonke, unfortunately this doesn't work on iOS Safari. My guess is because setting the thumb to `width: 0px;` for some reason makes it untouchable (even though no trouble with the mouse on desktop safari). If I make it larger like 20px then I can slide it but then it no longer works stylewise. I wonder if there is some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/MWVwJwj) by Noah Blon. A cross-browser range input slider. A box-shadow on the pseudo-thumb element creates a solid color fill effect¹. The `::-webkit-slider-thumb` is `width: 0` and `border: 0` makes it invisible yet it's functionality as a handle remains because it's `height: 40px`.

¹<sup>Also see this [article](https://www.sliderrevolution.com/resources/css-range-slider/)</sup>

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

input[type="range"] {
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0;
}

::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #ddd;
}


/*
 * 1. Set to 0 width and remove border for a slider without a thumb
 * 2. Shadow is negative the full width of the input and has a spread 
 *    of the width of the input.
 */

::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 0px;
  /* 1 */
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: -200px 0 0 200px dodgerblue;
  /* 2 */
  border: 0;
  /* 1 */
}

::-moz-range-track {
  height: 40px;
  background: #ddd;
}

::-moz-range-thumb {
  background: #fff;
  height: 40px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 3px solid #999;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: -200px 0 0 200px dodgerblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<input type='range'>
```

Comment: I get a thumb in Firefox with this one